# How to retrieve list of assets from Binance API?

Tags: binance

What is the Binance API endpoint (REST) where one can access a list of `ASSETS`, including `assetFullName`?

I have found reference to `GET /sapi/v1/margin/allAssets` but i can't access it via HTTP.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was missing something.  Binance does not expose this data on its public endpoints.

One must access private endpoint `/sapi/v1/margin/allAssets`

It is necessary to have [generated a Binance API key](https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/360002502072).

From PHP, [this simple curl wrapper](https://bestofphp.com/repo/mrcrypster-binance-php-php-third-party-apis) does the trick (and lots more).